# if column, row = something, echo something else echo error

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

How do I use php so it tests if a value in a mysql table is equal to a string? I am making a bans list and theres several categories, mutes, warnings and bans. The problem at the moment is they all display in every category so bans, mutes, warnings display in bans, mutes and warnings. They aren't sorted. I tried to fix it by using

```
<td>
<?php
    if($row['punishmentType'] == 'BAN') {
        echo "<img src='https://mcapi.ca/avatar/2d/" . $row['name'] . "/25' style='margin-bottom:5px;margin-right:5px;border-radius:2px;' />" . $row['name'];
    }
    else {
        echo 'ERROR'
    }
?>
</td>
```

But it comes up with ERROR. In the mysql table, theres 3 punishment types, BAN, MUTE and WARNING. Can someone tell me whats wrong with the code above? And how I fix it.

Comment: print `$row['punishmentType']` and see what it actually prints in the screen

Comment: Maybe the `$row['punishmentType']` returns Mute or Warning.

Comment: how do you define `$row`

Comment: check the column case or BAN case, maybe it is being saved as 'ban'. Or try printing $row['punishmentType'] to see what it actually contains as Thamilan mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if $row['punishmentType'] has content. Then you can use a `switch` statement to separate your logic according to the type of punishment.

You could do:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($row['punishmentType'])) {

         switch($row['punishmentType']) {

             case 'BAN': ...
                  break;
             case 'MUTE': ...
                  break;
             case 'WARNING': ...
                  break;   

    }
```